# Protractor with jest assertion framework

Tags: testing, protractor, jestjs, end-to-end

Using two different frameworks for unit and end-to-end testing seems not the best solution.

Is there any chance that jest will be added as supported protractor assertion framework?

Comment: This is not the best place to ask the question, it would be better to open an issue on github or join the Jest channel: https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103622435865104384

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a feature request to a aplication.